# Heroku deleting my images in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm doing a Django application and using heroku, but when I upload an image everything goes good, but after about 2 hours, heroku delete my images. I dont know what is happening. Im using a postgres db.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, but when i try to run my applicationaften an hor, all my images desapears

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't write anything to the file system, Heroku clearly states it's ephemeral and should not be used for anything.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Instead, you need to use a proper media storage backend, such as Amazon S3. For your Django project, check out django-storages with the S3 backend

http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also plan to add file to the db, as explained [here](http://mueller.panopticdev.com/2011/10/database-file-storage-for-django.html). This is good if you crane or bigger postgresql plans, so that you don't have to setup an S3 bucket.